# Reacting upon iTunes launch with NSDistributedNotificationCenter

Tags: macos, cocoa, itunes

I'm trying to intercept when iTunes starts up on Mac OS X, so I can relaunch my application to work around few bugs in the iTunes Framework.

What I did is to temporarly disable the sandboxing of my application and listen to all `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` notifications in order to examine them and pick the ones I want.

What I found is that upon start iTunes apparently sends this event:

```
object: com.apple.iTunes.help name: HelpBookRegistrationDidChange userInfo: (null)
```

which seems rather unique but also doesn't give an exact clue it is related to a startup event only at 100%.

Does anyone know if this is safe way to intercept such event?

If so, once my app is sandboxed again I need to ask temporary permission to listen to this kind of event, how can I do that in code?

Do you believe scripting bridge can help in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to disable sandboxing for this, just observe `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` in the notification center provided by `NSWorkspace`, not the distributed one.

You'll get an instance of `NSRunningApplication` in the user info of the notification, which you can use to determine whether the launched app was iTunes (use the `bundleIdentifier` property).

Comment: brilliant, thanks, I had to use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` though, with `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` I wasn't getting notified.

Comment: Right, I forgot that `NSWorkspace` has its own notification center.